# How do I show elements on mobile devices and tablets only with :not(hover)

Tags: css, responsive-design, hover, media-queries

I want the elements to show up on mobile devices but not on desktop as the element are controlled with a :hover. On mobile devices obviously you can't* :hover so I need them to show up. The problem is that even on the smaller widths, if one shrinks their desktop screen down to the smaller widths then the elements show up. I can't single out every device on the media queries so my elements only show up on mobile devices.

*EDIT: changed can to can't

```
 main class="animate__animated animate__slideInDown" id="cards">
<a href="signup.html">
    <section class="cards__med">
        <div class="cards__flexchild">
            <h1 class="cards__med-title">Medellín</h1>
            <img class="cards__medimage" src="img/medellin.jpeg" alt="medellin">
            <h2 class="cards__texthead" id="texthead_media640">The City of Eternal Spring</h2>
            <h2 class="choice" id="choice-media640">I choose Medellín!</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
</a>

    <a href="signup.html"><section class="cards__bog">
        <div>
            <h1 class="cards__bog-title">Bogotá</h1>
            <img class="cards__bogimage" src="img/bogota.jpg" alt="bogota">
            <h1 class="cards__texthead">The City where the Past and Present Meet</h1>
            
            <!-- <a href="signup.html" class="cards__bog-btn">Choose City</a> -->
        </div>
        <h2 class="choice">I choose Bogotá!</h2>
    
    </section></a>
    
    <a href="signup.html"><section class="cards__san">
        <div>
            <h1 class="cards__san-title">Santa Marta</h1>
            <img class="cards__santaimage" src="img/santa.jpg" alt="santa">
            <h1 class="cards__texthead" id="texthead__media1024">The Destination with Everything</h1>
            
            <!-- <a href="signup.html" class="cards__san-btn">Choose City</a> -->
        </div>
            <h2 class="choice" id="choice_santa">I choose Santa Marta!</h2>
    </section></a>
</main>



 #cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
        -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    /* animation: slide 1s; */
    /* transform: translateY(10rem); */
    
}

.cards__texthead {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    color:  var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.cards__med {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:  rgba(255, 236, 0, 0.65);
    height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: med_slide 1.25s;
}
.cards__med:hover {
    background:  rgba(255, 236, 0, 0.8);
}

.cards__med-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.cards__medimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__med:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

.choice {
    color: white;
    background: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    margin-top: 4.25rem;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 3.75rem;
}
.cards__med-btn {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    background:  var(--main-color);
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 14%;
    
}
.cards__bog {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: rgba(0, 17, 223, 0.65);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
        height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: bog_slide 1.5s;
}
.cards__bog:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 17, 223, 0.8);
}

.cards__bog-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.cards__bog-btn  {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    background:  var(--main-color);
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 14%;
}

.cards__bogimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

.cards__san {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 8, 0.65);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
        height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: san_slide 2s;
}
.cards__san:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 8, 0.8);
}
.cards__san-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color:  var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.cards__santaimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

@keyframes med_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.55rem);
    }
}

@keyframes bog_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-80rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.5rem);
    }
}

@keyframes san_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-60rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.5rem);
    }
}

    @media (hover: none) {
    .cards__san:hover .choice,
    .cards__med:hover .choice,
    .cards__bog:hover .choice  {
      display: inherit;
    }
  }

@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1366px)
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1450px) {
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 330px;
        height: 220px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 27rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }

    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 4.5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }
     
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
    #choice-media640 {
        margin-top: 2.8rem ;
    }
    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 3.5rem;
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 290px;
        height: 180px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 19rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
    #choice-media640 {
        margin-top: 2.8rem ;
    }
    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
   
    .title {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        /*width: 21.5rem;*/
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 230px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 29rem;
        width: 17rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: 0rem;
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
   
    .title {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        /*width: 21.5rem;*/
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 230px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 29rem;
        width: 17rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: 0rem;
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While as you say you cannot test for every single device (and it's an insecure thing to do anyway) you can test, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) puts it, to see if

> the primary input mechanism can conveniently hover over elements.

I am not sure exactly how 'conveniently' is defined here, but MDN deems having to do a long touch as not in that category.

Here's their example as a snippet:

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
  a:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Try hovering over me!</a>
```

ADDITION:
To stop the choice elements showing when the user is on a device that has a conveniently usable hover (as per the browser's understanding of 'convenient') then we need to stop the display of choice whatever the width of the screen.

```
 @media (hover: hover) {
    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

This says: when the user can hover don't show the choice element. We need to put this after all the other media settings so it overwrites anything they may have set for the display of choice. In this snippet it is therefore right at the end:

```css
#cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
        -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    /* animation: slide 1s; */
    /* transform: translateY(10rem); */
    
}

.cards__texthead {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    color:  var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.cards__med {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background:  rgba(255, 236, 0, 0.65);
    height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: med_slide 1.25s;
}
.cards__med:hover {
    background:  rgba(255, 236, 0, 0.8);
}

.cards__med-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.cards__medimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__med:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

.choice {
    color: white;
    background: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    margin-top: 4.25rem;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 3.75rem;
}
.cards__med-btn {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    background:  var(--main-color);
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 14%;
    
}
.cards__bog {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: rgba(0, 17, 223, 0.65);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
        height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: bog_slide 1.5s;
}
.cards__bog:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 17, 223, 0.8);
}

.cards__bog-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.cards__bog-btn  {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    background:  var(--main-color);
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 14%;
}

.cards__bogimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

.cards__san {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 8, 0.65);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: .1;
        -ms-flex-positive: .1;
            flex-grow: .1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 30rem;
        flex-basis: 30rem;
        height: 35rem;
    width: 30rem;
    animation: san_slide 2s;
}
.cards__san:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 8, 0.8);
}
.cards__san-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background: white;
    color:  var(--main-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.cards__santaimage {
    width: 412px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
    display: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

@keyframes med_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-100rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.55rem);
    }
}

@keyframes bog_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-80rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.5rem);
    }
}

@keyframes san_slide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-60rem);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(1.5rem);
    }
}

    @media (hover: none) {
    .cards__san:hover .choice,
    .cards__med:hover .choice,
    .cards__bog:hover .choice  {
      display: inherit;
    }
  }

@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1366px)
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1450px) {
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 330px;
        height: 220px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 27rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }

    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 4.5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }
     
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
    #choice-media640 {
        margin-top: 2.8rem ;
    }
    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 3.5rem;
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 290px;
        height: 180px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 19rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
    #choice-media640 {
        margin-top: 2.8rem ;
    }
    #choice_santa {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .title {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 310px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 32rem;
        width: 21.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        /*margin-left: .5rem;*/
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.75rem;
    }
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
   
    .title {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        /*width: 21.5rem;*/
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 230px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 29rem;
        width: 17rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: 0rem;
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
   
    .title {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        /*width: 21.5rem;*/
        border: 2px black solid;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cards {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .cards__medimage,
    .cards__bogimage,
    .cards__santaimage {
        width: 230px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .cards__med,
    .cards__bog,
    .cards__san {
        height: 29rem;
        width: 17rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        border: 3px black solid;
        margin-left: 0rem;
    }

    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .choice {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
 }
 @media (hover: hover) {
    .cards__med:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__bog:not(:hover) .choice,
    .cards__san:not(:hover) .choice {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

```html
  <main class="animate__animated animate__slideInDown" id="cards">
<a href="signup.html">
    <section class="cards__med">
        <div class="cards__flexchild">
            <h1 class="cards__med-title">Medellín</h1>
            <img class="cards__medimage" src="img/medellin.jpeg" alt="medellin">
            <h2 class="cards__texthead" id="texthead_media640">The City of Eternal Spring</h2>
            <h2 class="choice" id="choice-media640">I choose Medellín!</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
</a>

    <a href="signup.html"><section class="cards__bog">
        <div>
            <h1 class="cards__bog-title">Bogotá</h1>
            <img class="cards__bogimage" src="img/bogota.jpg" alt="bogota">
            <h1 class="cards__texthead">The City where the Past and Present Meet</h1>
            
            <!-- <a href="signup.html" class="cards__bog-btn">Choose City</a> -->
        </div>
        <h2 class="choice">I choose Bogotá!</h2>
    
    </section></a>
    
    <a href="signup.html"><section class="cards__san">
        <div>
            <h1 class="cards__san-title">Santa Marta</h1>
            <img class="cards__santaimage" src="img/santa.jpg" alt="santa">
            <h1 class="cards__texthead" id="texthead__media1024">The Destination with Everything</h1>
            
            <!-- <a href="signup.html" class="cards__san-btn">Choose City</a> -->
        </div>
            <h2 class="choice" id="choice_santa">I choose Santa Marta!</h2>
    </section></a>
</main>
```

Comment: I don;'t understand your answer.  Is there a setting that allows me to display an element only on mobile devices/tablets?

Comment: I thought you wanted to display an element only if there was no hover facility. So use the media query, putting the CSS to show what you want to show, having it not display outside the media query perhaps (e.g. with display: none)?

Comment: I want the element to remain invisible unless someone is using a mobile device or tablet.   Media queries just target scree n size.  If you resize the desktop screen to a smaller width it will do everything in the media query,  I was wondering if there was a setting that lets things stay hidden when using a desktop or laptop compuiter.

Comment: Hi, I think it's worth you looking at the MDN reference linked in my answer. Media queries do lots of things, not just viewport size. In this case I am suggesting you look at the hover media query - you can then display or not the info depending on this.

Comment: I have read through it and I don't understand it.

Comment: Which elements do you want to show if the user is on a device where they can't easily (conveneiently) hover?

Comment: .choice {
    color: white;
    background: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    margin-top: 4.25rem;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: 3.75rem;

Comment: If you run the code, you will mouse over each card and see a message.  Now shrink the screen size on your computer down and you will see that at smaller widths they show up.  I don't wantthat to happen on computers but I do for tablet/phones.

Comment: Could you make your code into a snippet so I can run it? I don't see any media queries - what am I mssing?

Comment: I don't knoew how to do that.  I'm sorry i forgot the queries.  Edited

Comment: Use the media hover query to unset choice's display when the user is able to hover. See my updated answer.

Comment: Works for me what browser and system are you using?

Comment: Chrome, unless I am just doing it wrong. Do I just put the media query above all the other ones?

Comment: No, the media query must go after all the other CSS so it overwrites it. Have you run the snippet (not copied it or anything) as here? How are you making the viewport narrower?

Comment: I worked! So that was my problem, i didn't put it last.   Thanks!